# push to specific position of array

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert into array at a specified place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763959/insert-into-array-at-a-specified-place)

How to push 1 or more values to middle (or a specific position/index) of an array?
for example:

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'e', 'f');
array_pushTo($a, 1, 'c', 'd'); // that function i'm looking for. first parameter is the array, second is the index, and third and other are the values.
// $a now is: array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
```

Comment: `array_splice()` http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Comment: This should help you :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/php-array-insert-new-item-in-any-position

Comment: There is an answer below that could do with being accepted.

Comment: @RichardHedges: Wow! Thanks, after 2+ years, when I forgot it completely, I marked the best answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice) is probably what you're looking for:

```
array_splice($a, 1, 0, array('c', 'd'));
```