# Chronological numbers order - PHP

Tags: php, math, loops, numbers

I need to find the chronological next number.
For example , I have an array :

```
$numbers = array(1,2,4);
```

I want function give me the missing chronological number : `3`

more example :

```
$numbers = array(6,7,8,11);
```

need to give me : `9`

Thanks

Comment: On the second array, why not 10? Also, what have you tried? This smells suspiciously of homework.

Comment: Still, a challenge is a challenge!  I'm 95% sure it's homework, but we all needed to learn somewhere.  At least this person bothered to format the post instead of copy-pasting it, complete with corrupt MS Word characters.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I see doing this is to use `sort` on your array, then looping through the entire array.

To insert the number at the specified position in the array, [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763959/insert-into-array-at-a-specified-place).

Use nickb's answer though - much better!

Comment: there is no built in function called array_sort(), perhaps you are referring to sort()?

Comment: @JoshuaBurns Yeah, I was, I just fixed it.  Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple once you make the assumption that the array is sorted with:

```
sort( $numbers);
```

Then, you can get the complete range of numbers, do a difference on the complete set and the input array, and take the first element (which will be the first element that differs):

Since the array is sorted, we can grab the min and max elements like this (we could also call [`min()`](http://php.net/min) and [`max()`](http://php.net/max)):

```
$min = current( $numbers);
$max = end( $numbers);
```

Now, we use [`range()`](http://php.net/range) to get the complete set of numbers, then call [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff) to find the difference:

```
$complete = range( $min, $max);
$diff = array_diff( $complete, $numbers);
```

The first consecutive missing number is in the first element in the difference:

```
$first_missing = array_shift( $diff);
```

The benefit here is that `$diff` will contain **all** of the missing numbers between the range of `$min` and `$max`.

Comment: Good point - but if you're getting the min and max of the array, why not just use that range to *replace* the array?  EDIT: The OP was edited, not sure if he wants the array filled in or to get the first missing number.

Comment: @Jaxo - I think he is looking for the first missing number. If he wants the array filled it, this also does that with the `$complete` variable. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php
function chrono_trigger($array) {
    sort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
    $prev = False;
    foreach($array as $num) {
        if($prev === False) {
            $prev = $num;
            continue;
        }
        if($prev != ($num-1)) {
            return $prev+1;
        }
        $prev = $num;
    }
    return False;
}

$numbers1 = array(1,2,4); // Should return 3
$numbers2 = array(6,7,8,11); // Should return 9
$numbers3 = array(1,2,3,4); // Shouldn't return anything

// Returns 3
$missing1 = chrono_trigger($numbers1);
var_export($missing1);

// Returns 9
$missing2 = chrono_trigger($numbers2);
var_export($missing2);

// Returns False
$missing3 = chrono_trigger($numbers3);
var_export($missing3);
```